# Cannot build solution because of log4net dependency issues C#

Tags: c#, build, dependencies, .net-assembly

I am currently working on my colleague's project that he wrote a few years ago. The project uses "log4net" assembly although I do not really need it or use it. Anyways, when I'm trying to build project, i get this error:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fea11e3513f1a42' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.'  VersionChecker  C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFx.targets   268
```

I've tried to remove the assembly, and also tried to redirect assembly versions without luck. I don't find any trace to log4net anywhere in my project and don't have a clue how to remove it completely and manage to build my project..

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hope you had tried it already, Pick up all useful pages and stuff from current project and put them in a new solution and build fresh.

Comment: I keep this solution to the end.. Building it fresh usually causes me a new set of problems.. like loss of configurations and so on

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'Manage Nuget Packages for Solution' from Tools menu of VS and check if you could uninstall it from there.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see it there.. Those are DLLs imported to the project - it wasn't installed through any manager.. maybe this is the reason

Comment: Does the web.config have reference of log4net?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of building projects. The most common way is to use Visual Studio only. If this is your case, then simply go through each project in your solution explorer and expand references. You should see all the references to your project. Simply highlight Log4Net and press the delete key.  You'll need to go through all the code that references Log4Net and remove it.

The other scenario is that you're using an external build script, like msbuild to do additional compilation.  If this is the case you'll need to wade through your build scripts. The details vary among implementation, but a starting point is to simply highlight the project in question in the solution explorer and press alt+enter to bring up the properties.  Check the build events tab for additional build script info.

Comment: My case is the first one you've mentioned in your answer. Already said, I did try to remove the assembly and every peace of code that is related to it, but it still won't build.

Comment: Did you check the build scripts in the project properties?